# Check if an Integer is a whole Number using Javascript

Tags: javascript, web, math, error-handling

Below is my code block, when I run this it is still returning values with a decimal place. Such as 15 / 2 = 7.5, instead of 8 which it should do. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

`answer = x /y;`

```
if (Number.isInteger(answer) == false) {
        Math.round(answer);
        return answer;
    }
else return answer;
}
```

Comment: There are a few syntax error, could you please correct them ?

Comment: Is there any reason you need to check if its an integer? ``round(4) == 4`` so you can just have ``return Math.round(answer)`` with no need for the conditional check

Answer (score 2):

The Math.round function will round off the "answer" variable, but you forgot to pass the rounded off value back to the "answer" variable.

```
if (Number.isInteger(answer) == false) {
    answer = Math.round(answer);
    return answer;
   }
else return answer;
}
```

Comment: As I stated too. It is also clumsy to test a boolean with `== false` instead of `!` or even testing false first

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `answer = Math.round(answer);` or just `return Math.round(answer);`

Also testing a boolean == false is a bit clumsy. Better to reverse the test and test for true

To keep your syntax

```js
function roundInt(answer) {
  if (Number.isInteger(answer)) {
    return answer
  } 
  else {
    return Math.round(answer);
  }
}
console.log(roundInt(15 / 2))
console.log(roundInt(16 / 2))
console.log(roundInt(19 / 2))
```

Here is a shorter version

```js
const roundInt = answer => Number.isInteger(answer) ? answer : Math.round(answer);

console.log(roundInt(15/2))
console.log(roundInt(16/2))
console.log(roundInt(19/2))
```